# How is $\mathbb{F}_4$ generated?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I know $\mathbb{F}_4$ is a field while $\mathbb{Z}/(4)$ is just a ring. So how is $\mathbb{F}_4$ generated?

**Complement**: So what are the elements like in $\mathbb{F}_4$ like? Are they $\{0,1,x,x+1\}$? Is every field $\mathbb{F}_k$ has $k$ elements no matter whether $k$ is a prime?

Comment: $\mathbb F_4\cong \mathbb F_2[x]/(x^2+x+1)$.

Comment: @Nishant: You should convert this to an answer.

Comment: Can it be formed by killing other quadratic polynomials?@Nishant

Comment: @user115512 you can form the field by killing any irreducible quadratic polynomial in $\mathbb{Z}_2$.  Notice, however, that $x^2 + x + 1$ is the only irreducible quadratic in $Z_2$ with coefficients in $Z_2$.

Comment: $x^2+x+1$ is the only irreducible quadratic in $\mathbb{F}_2[x]$.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom - Didn't mean to repeat you. I must have been composing my comment while you were posting.

Comment: Note there need not exist fields $\mathbb{F}_k$ for every positive integer $k$. When $k$ is prime, then this field exists and has $k$ elements. All finitie fields are of order $k=p^n$ (e.g., is the power of a prime). These fields have $k$ elements.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As Nishant said $\mathbb{F}_4\approx \mathbb{F}_2[X]/(X^2+X+1)$.

Since this polynomial ($p:=X^2+X+1$) has no solution in $\mathbb{F}_2$, you can show that extending $\mathbb{F}_2\to\mathbb{F}_2[\theta]\subset K$ where $\theta$ is a solution of $p$ in an algebraic closure $K$, you get that $\mathbb{F}_4$ and these two fields are isomorphic. Notice that all fields of 4 elements are isomorphic.

Comment: Is it right to write $\mathbb{F}_4\sim \mathbb{F}_2[X]/(X^2+X+1)$ but not $\mathbb{F}_4\approx\mathbb{F}_2[X]/(X^2+X+1)$?

Comment: I didn't say it was wrong. Ah, I used the wrong symbol. Thanks for noting. I´ll edit my answer.

Answer (score 2):

The answer of @MarceloBielsa is perfect, but I like an approach like what OP was working towards: the elements of $\mathbb F_4$ are $\{0,1,\omega,\omega+1\}$, where $\omega^2=\omega+1$, $(\omega+1)^2=\omega$, and $\omega(\omega+1)=1$. I think that that’s enough for filling in the multiplication table.